# How Can I get current location

Tags: java, android, latitude-longitude, android-location, android-gps

I have a problem with my application on Android. I use this class:

```
package com.example.seadog.gps;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private Context mContext;

    public GPSTracker() {

    }

    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;

    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 5000;

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {

            } else {

                this.canGetLocation = true;

                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (isGPSEnabled) {

                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        return longitude;
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }


    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS jest wyłączony");

        alertDialog.setMessage("Do używania tej aplikacji wymagany jest GPS. W tym celu przejdź do ustawień, włącz GPS a następnie uruchom ponownie.");

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ustawienia", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Anuluj", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });


        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        int ID = GlobalConfig.ID;
        int Random = GlobalConfig.Random;

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        try {

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("ID", ID);
            json.put("Random", Random);
            json.put("latitude", latitude);
            json.put("longitude", longitude);

            GlobalConfig config = new GlobalConfig();
            config.set(json);
            //config.i(0);

        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

This class is taken from the internet. I added own code in OnChangedLocation. When the coordinates are changing, then creating a JSONObject with new latitude and longitude in GlobalConfig class.
In another class there is a Service, which sends a data to server every 5 second in background.
My problem is that the latitude and longitude aren't correct. Sometimes the value obtained is right and other time it is not. The location remains same for about 10 or few minutes and after a while correct value is shown.
My app works in background. On the browser I had a preview on google map and my marker jumps on the map. I tested it while driving a car.

Something is wrong. I would like to get the correct latitude and longitude. Help!

Comment: This type of question already asked

Comment: You should use the search function and look at the google-manual [API Guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the Position of an Android phone by using GPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651499/getting-the-position-of-an-android-phone-by-using-gps)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to receive location updates every 5 minutes using the FusedLocation API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32979633/how-to-receive-location-updates-every-5-minutes-using-the-fusedlocation-api)

Comment: This does not solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

You should use the last Google API to location. First, you connect with this API like this:

```
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(locationClientCallback)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(locationClientCallback)
                    .build();

if (!(googleApiClient.isConnected() || googleApiClient.isConnecting())) {
       googleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Now, in your locationClientCallback you receive if the API is connected or not.

```
private class LocationClientCallback implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location == null) {
                return;
            }

            // YOU HAVE YOUR POSITION

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
            // CONNECTION FAILED
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
            // GOOGLE API CONNECTED 


            // MAKE A REQUEST FOR LOCATIONS
            LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
            request.setSmallestDisplacement(0);
            request.setInterval(5000);
            request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, request, this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
            // CONNECTION SUSPENDED

        }


    }
```

And in the callbacks you receive the positions and other events. In onConnected event you should request for locations to Google API Client.

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: I mean this is not. I create app for drivers. My app works in background even when app is hidden or a smartphone is in sleep mode. Every 5 seconds a device sends a data to server with a location but here is a problem. This location is wrong. Only sometimes is correct. I want only correct latitude and longitude in my database then I lay these items on the google map on the website.

Comment: The correct way to get locations is this. This code you should execute in a service. In the location you had a field that indicate the accuracy of the location, If the accuracy is very high you can rule out the position.

Comment: I'll tell you that I don't know how it use. I have a libraries marked in red. Can I need to have API Key from google and if I have a GPSTracker, do I have to remove it and create new LocationClientCallback class with implements... ?

Comment: You need add Google Play services. If you are using Gradle in your project you can add with this:  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0" Now, implements the funcionality in a new service: connect google api and implements the LocationClientCallbacks

Comment: Yes, I use Gradle. I added this, but now I have a problem with resolve symbol R e.g. setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: OK, I resolve this problem. Now I marked in red this line: .addConnectionCallbacks(locationClientCallback) and this: .addOnConnectionFailedListener(locationClientCallback) and I have a title that LocationClientCallback is never used. What is wrong?

Comment: LocationclientCallback is a class, you need declare your own object locationClientCallback = new LocationClientCallback() and pass in addOnconne...(locationClientcallback)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96884/discussion-between-seadog-and-alejandro-martinez-martinez).

Comment: I have strange problem. I create new GoogleApiClient.Builder in onCreate method() in MainActivity class with implements GoogleApi... and I can't connect to LocationServices.API. I'm testing that on android 2.3.6. How to fix this problem?

Comment: OK, I resolved my problem. It work perfectly on KitKat but it not working on android 2.3.6 any ideas?